# Export Function and Prototype from one file to another

Tags: javascript

I need to export all things (function and prototype) from one file (name:config.js) to another file (name:index.js) that will use them 
I need to create ws in Javascript with Node.js on "Sublime",
and the error said when in ran my code at `cmd` that `'plus' in not defined`.

```
code :(config.js)-first file

var Ranking=function(){
    this.rank= 5;
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
};
var printName=function(){
    console.log("spa name is: sea spa");
};
Ranking.prototype.plus =function(sum){
    this.rank += sum;
    this.emit("change"); 
};
Ranking.prototype.minus =function(sum){
    this.rank -= sum;
    this.emit("change"); 
};
var addingStar=function(){
    console.log("the ranking is: " + this.rank);
};
var changeNoZero=function(){
    if(this.rank<0){
        console.log("bad reviews " + this.rank);
    }
};

module.exports=Ranking;
```

index.js -second file

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
var Ranking = require('./config');
var ranking = new Ranking();
util.inherits(Ranking ,events.EventEmitter);


ranking.on("change",printName);
ranking.on("change",addingStar);
ranking.on("change",changeNoZero);


ranking.plus(1);
ranking.minus(6);
ranking.plus(3);
```

Comment: the error is in command line (cmd) when i ran the code he worte me :"plus is not defined"

Comment: What are you asking!? What "error", an error in Sublime text?
What is the command-line that you are running?

Comment: I wirte this code in "Sblime Text" but I ran it from cmd (its call command-line) and ther i have an error :" events is not defined" if you use apple its called command key i think so

Answer (score -1):

You can try something as below :

Config.js file ----

```
var defaultValues = module.exports

defaultValues.GetApiURL = function () {
var apiURL = "http://localhost:1000/api/"
return apiURL;
}
```

index.js ----

```
var defaultValues = require('./config.js');
var apiUrl= defaultValues.GetApiURL();
```

Comment: i try this change but its dosent work its still give me an error that said:"event is not define" this message refer to config.js to line: events.EventsEmmiter.call(this);

Comment: did you install event package using npm?